# How to setup syslog forwarding for systemd journal namespace

Tags: systemd, syslog, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I have a configuration `/etc/systemd/journald@my-namespace.conf` which contains the setting `ForwardToSyslog=yes` and a systemd service unit configured with `LogNamespace=my-namespace`.

The documentation after this is not clear to me how to get the journal logs from my-namespace forwarded to syslog.

I understand there are two ways of forwarding journal logs to syslog, through a UNIX domain socket or .journal file. For this case, let's say I want to setup a socket at `/run/systemd/journal.my-namespace/syslog` for journald to write logs to and rsyslogd to listen and forward to syslog. I have gone through the documentation but I still don't understand how I would configure this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a minimal solution after reading the [rsyslog docs](https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules/imuxsock.html) which is to create an rsyslog config file `/etc/rsyslog.d/my-namespace.conf` with the content:

```
input(type="imuxsock" Socket="/run/systemd/journal.my-namespace/syslog")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `rsyslog.conf`

Following [this guide](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/centralizing-with-syslog/), I added to the local syslog client, file `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```text
module(load="imjournal")
```

[rsyslog module `imjournal`](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imjournal.html) is especially for journal log messages.
The same `/etc/rsyslog.conf` already has UDP forwarding set

```text
*.* @some-remote-syslog-server.local:514
```

Then restart `rsyslog`

```text
systemctl restart rsyslog.service
```

#### test

On the remote syslog server, `tail` the collected syslogs for that host (this path will depend on the remote syslog server configuration)

```text
$ tail -F /var/log/rsyslog/my-host/*
```

On the local syslog server, follow the journal logs

```text
$ journalctl -xf
```

Then create log messages using both the old `logger` program and the new `systemd-cat` program

```
$ echo MESSAGE FROM $(hostname) USING logger | logger -t user
$ echo MESSAGE FROM $(hostname) USING systemd-cat | systemd-cat -t user
```

(the log message tag `user` is arbitrary)

In my case, both messages, via `logger` and via `systemd-cat`, appeared in both places, the remote syslog server and the local journal logs.

This Answer does not attempt to delineate namespaces. But it did what I wanted which was to forward all journal log messages.